# selenium python error 'dict' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
if href.startswith("https://store.steampowered"):
    browser.get(href)

    if browser.current_url.startswith("https://store.steampowered.com/agecheck"):
        area = browser.find_element_by_id("agecheck_form")
        location_field = area.find_element_by_id("ageYear")

        for option in location_field.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"):
            if int(option.text) == 1999:
                option.click()
                break

            enter = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agecheck_form"]/a')
            enter.location_once_scrolled_into_view.click()
```

My intention for this bit of code is to go to a steam game page to grab the price of the game. If it encounters the age check wall it runs my above code.

https://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/489830/

My problem is no matter what way I format the click event on the enter button, it gives me the error:  'dict' object has no attribute 'click'

I have searched into what dictionaries are and still am stumped.
I have my suspicions that this problem could be related to my option loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location_once_scrolled_into_view` returns dictionary, the `x` and `y` coordinates of the `webelement`. Just remove it, selenium will scroll automatically to the `webelement` before the click.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew it would've been something simple/stupid

Comment: I have the same problem, I had to downgrade selenium to make it work. Can you please elaborate on your solution, I dont understand it fully

Comment: @Ash the solution was to remove `location_once_scrolled_into_view` and just click on the element, I'm not really sure what I can add to that.