# Selenium Chromedriver : 'dict' object has no attribute 'click' for find_element() method when w3c is disabled

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Just started experimenting with selenium and chromedriver, and I've an error in a specific configuration.
I always get : `'dict' object has no attribute 'click'` when I call `find_element()` method or `find_element_by_*` methods.

I've found that the line:

```
options.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)
```

caused the issue but didn't understand why and how to fix this.
Questions:
- Is it the normal behaviour ?
- An idea on how to fix this ?

***Info : I disabled w3c to be able to retrieve performance logs (Network) for status code.***

Here a standalone test code I made :

```
import os
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

# Get Chrome Driver Fullpath
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DRIVER_FULLPATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "chromedriver")


# Options
options = Options()

## Enable headless
options.headless = False
# Disable w3c to be able to retrieve performance logs
options.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)

# Specify custom chromedriver path
service = Service(DRIVER_FULLPATH)

# Create a DesiredCapabilities object
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()

# Enable Network logging here too
capabilities['perfLoggingPrefs'] = ['enableNetwork']

# Instantiate the Driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service, desired_capabilities={'loggingPrefs': {'performance': 'INFO'}})

# The URL we want to load first (entry point)
url = 'https://www.python.org/'

# Load the page
driver.get(url)

# Get Logs
logs = driver.get_log('performance')

# Go through logs and find latest network response to get code status
for log_index in range(1,len(logs)+1):
    message = json.loads(logs[log_index]['message'])['message']
    if message and message['method'] == 'Network.responseReceived':
        status_code = message['params']['response']['status']
        # For demo purpose only print the status
        print('Page status : ' + str(status_code))
        break

# Select the radio button
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("donate-button")
# OR elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "donate-button")

# This below will fail (raise error) since I disable w3c but how to fix that ?
elem.click()

input('Press ENTER to close the automated browser')

# Exit
driver.quit()
```

My configuration :

- Mac OS Big Sur 11.5
- Python 3.9.6
- Selenium 4.0.0.b4
- Chrome 92.0.4515.131
- ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.43

Comment: Already checked  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674355/selenium-python-error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-click but I'm my case normally ```find_element_by_*``` returns a Webelem object, but disabling w3c seems to change the behaviour.

Comment: Had the same problem with getting Dict. For my purpose, enabling w3c allowed the elements to be clicked again

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the exact same situation, but downgrading the selenium version to 3.141.0 solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tested that, this can be a good workaround :)

Comment: this worked for me, need to read selenium4.0 docs to see how click has been changed